# Error when comparing the values of the same variable

Tags: php

I'm having a little problem with validation. I have here this code snippet that works by this way: if the `pizza_size` variable is not set in the Query String and the ID of product category is 1 (corresponds to pizzas) or this is set but the `pizza_size` value is not equal to `small`, `medium` or `big` this needs to return to the page `products.php` with the message that the size is not selected. I'm trying with:

```
if(!isset($_GET['pizza_size']) || $_GET['pizza_size'] != "small" || $_GET['pizza_size'] != "medium" || $_GET['pizza_size'] != "big" && $category_id == 1)
{
    redirect_to('products.php?message=no-size-informed');
}
else //Add the product
```

The problem is that this is not working. Even if the `pizza_size` corresponds to `small`, `medium` or `big` I receive the error message. But if I use only one comparison, this works great, like:

```
if(!isset($_GET['pizza_size']) || $_GET['pizza_size'] != "small" && $category_id == 1)
{
    redirect_to('products.php?message=no-size-informed');
}
```

But I need to validate with the 3 sizes. How to do this validation with all the three possible variables? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you put extra set of parentheses around the middle part?     if(!isset($_GET['pizza_size']) || ($_GET['pizza_size'] != "small" || $_GET['pizza_size'] != "medium" || $_GET['pizza_size'] != "big") && $category_id == 1)

Comment: AND operator will apply first,,, so it will give error if $_GET['pizza_size'] doesn't exist  ... @Dyan by the way what is your error

Comment: @veelen Same thing. I have the error mesage even the size is small, medium or big.

Comment: @MohammadAlabed I have the message "No size for the Pizza informed" even if the size variable is small, medium or big.

Comment: Try wrapping all the `or` in `()` like `((..or....or..) && )`

Comment: your problem is the understanding of the Brackets job and the Operator Precedence ,, so UpVoted to @frz3993 and it is the correct answer

Comment: @MohammadAlabed yes! LSW code did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(($category_id == 1)
   && !(isset($_GET['pizza_size']) && in_array($_GET['pizza_size'], array('small', 'medium', 'big')))
) {
    redirect_to('products.php?mesage=no-size-informed');
}
else {
   // Add the product
}
```

Comment: this will cause a `undefined` notice if `$_GET['pizza_size']` is not set, which is why the OP begins with `!isset($_GET['pizza_size'])`

Comment: @Sean, well spotted. I've amended the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like this:

```
if(($category_id == 1)
   && (isset($_GET['pizza_size'] && !in_array($_GET['pizza_size'], array('small', 'medium', 'big')) || !isset($_GET['pizza_size']
) {
    redirect_to('products.php?mesage=no-size-informed');
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to check `... && (!isset($_GET['pizza_size'] || !in_array($_GET['pizza_size'], ...`

Comment: That's right, but if the in_array function is invoked with a non existing variable, a error may occur, so you first have to check if the variable is set.